# How to update EventKit Add Event title from my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I'm getting a data from the rss feed in which i get the title, date and urllink i'm showing the title and date in my tableView and displaying the urllink in the detailView .
In this detail view i'm giving the UIBarButton

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bell.png" ] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addEvent:)];
```

addEvent method is used to for giving the EventKit option...

```
-(IBAction) addEvent:(id)sender {

EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
[self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

addController.editViewDelegate = self;
[addController release];
}
```

after clicking on this addButtonItem we get Add Event screen in this screen first option is Title and Location i Want to update this "Title" option with my data getting from RssFeed.

[image]

How can i update this from my app with my RSSFeed Title data where should i do the changes ...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually doing it right... but the EKEventViewController object has an event property that you can use to set all the properties like you want. Create the event with the properties you want, start time, end time, title, etc, and set the event property of the EKEventViewController before you display it.

```
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title     = @"Whatever you want your title to be";

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    event.startDate = [NSDate date]; // or however you are setting your start date
    event.endDate   = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];
    event.allDay    = YES; // or NO

    EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    addController.event = event;
    addController.eventStore = eventStore;
    addController.editViewDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];
```